# Mysql no me permite alterar tabla para añadir foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
alter table users add CONSTRAINT fk_users_user FOREIGN key(`users_user`) REFERENCES sessions(sess_user);
```

Pero al ejecutarla, mysql me da el siguiente error:

> MySQL said: #1005 - Can't create table `software`.`#sql-1584_e2f`
>   (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Ésta es mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
create table users(
    users_id int primary key,
    users_user varchar(50),
    users_password varchar(50),
    users_lastSession int(10),
    users_role int(10)
)

create table sessions(
    sess_id int primary key,
    sess_date date,
    sess_ip int(15),
    sess_user varchar(50),
    sess_numSession int(255)
)
```

No estoy creando una tabla, aparte lo estoy haciendo dentro de la base de datos, por lo que no entiendo a qué se debe dicho error, si no estoy queriendo ni insertar una tabla, ni nada con el nombre software (software es el nombre de la db). Alguien tiene idea de qué sucede?

Comment: Bienvenido David! Revisa la documentación para crear una [foreign_key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Gracias, pero no noto que esté haciendo algo mal. De la misma forma pude relacionar otra tabla, pero por alguna razón no puedo con ésta.

Comment: por favor agrega la estructura de tus tablas como texto y no como imagen, para poder reproducir el ejercicio y ayudarte

Comment: @anonimo Hecho, espero ayude.

Comment: Lol muchas gracias, a veces me confundo con las relaciones.

Comment: Pon todo el código que estás usando. El error habla de un problema con un `CREATE TABLE`, no con la sentencia de la llave foránea: **`MySQL said: #1005 - Can't create table software.#sql-1584_e2f`**. Lo dice clarísimamente: _Can't **create table**
 software._